# oracle sqlplus report compute columns

Tags: oracle, report, sqlplus

new to this site, so I may not be formatting things right

I have a SQLPlus report that has a very unique requirement that I can't seem to figure out. What I need to do is based on the total value of a break column display a piece of text that says 'Available' or 'Full'.

Here is what the report looks like:

```
date    column 1    column 2      count
=====   ========    ========      =====
1/5/14  ABC         ABC           10
        DEF         DEF           20
******                            -----
total                             30 - this would be a normal compute when break on date
```

What I need to do is compare that total count field (30 in this case) and if it is > a hard-coded value (say 20) print 'Full' otherwise 'Available'.  I'm open to any suggestions, I don't have to print the 30 if there is a way to substitute the text in its place or print on another line or next to it somewhere (Or even if I can make the label say text I want).  Issue I have is applying that compare logic in the sqlplus report itself.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

SQLPlus has only basic reporting features. In particular, you can't really customize most of its features like [`BREAK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve009.htm#i2696939) and [`COMPUTE SUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve014.htm#i2697257).

However, you can use all of SQL features so you can probably customize your SQL to get the result you want. Something like this:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2  SELECT DATE '2014-05-01' d, 'ABC' c1, 'ABC' c2, 10 cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT DATE '2014-05-01' d, 'DEF' c1, 'DEF' c2, 20 cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT DATE '2014-06-01' d, 'GHI' c1, 'GHI' c2, 10 cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT DATE '2014-06-01' d, 'JKL' c1, 'JKL' c2, 5 cnt FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT CASE
  8           WHEN GROUPING(c1) = 1 THEN '**Total**'
  9           ELSE to_char(d, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
 10         END dt,
 11         c1, c2, SUM(cnt),
 12         CASE
 13           WHEN GROUPING(c1) = 1 AND SUM(cnt) > 20 THEN 'Full'
 14           WHEN GROUPING(c1) = 1 AND SUM(cnt) <= 20 THEN 'Available'
 15         END AVAILABILITY
 16    FROM DATA
 17  GROUP BY d, ROLLUP ((c1, c2));

DT         C1  C2    SUM(CNT) AVAILABILITY
---------- --- --- ---------- ------------
01/05/2014 ABC ABC         10 
01/05/2014 DEF DEF         20 
**Total**                  30 Full
01/06/2014 GHI GHI         10 
01/06/2014 JKL JKL          5 
**Total**                  15 Available

6 rows selected
```

For further reading: an [excellent article about GROUP BY, ROLLUP and CUBE by Rob van Wijk](http://www.rwijk.nl/AboutOracle/All%20About%20Grouping.ppt).

Comment: This is excellent information that I will certainly keep mind.  However, I had to change my approach due to a customer requirement change that simplified it.  Thanks again.